# prePersist hook when creating article

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I'm trying to create an article with the [Sonata Admin Bundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html).

I have an item with a field itemApproved. This is a datetime field. But I show the field as a checkbox like this:

```
$formMapper
    ->add('itemTitle', 'text', array('label' => 'Article Title'))
    ->add('itemApproved', 'checkbox', array(
        'label'     => 'Approved',
        'required'  => false,
    ))
;
```

Now I would like to check if the checkbox is checked. If yes -> set datetime.

I'm trying to do this like so:

```
public function prePersist($article)
{
    if($article->getitemApproved())
    {
        $article->setitemApproved(new \DateTime());
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting this error:

```
Expected a Boolean.
```

Because he still thinks it's a checkbox. How could I fix the right way?

Comment: why don't you save it as a boolean field in database and also note time every entry and perform your further logic when you have approved 1 save in database simple add new field for datetime and other field for checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set datetime in the controller before executing `$em->flush();` if the checkbox is set to true. In your example you can use additional field that is not in entity. You'll have to add [mapped false](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) so that exception wouldn't be thrown.

```
 $formMapper
    ->add('itemTitle', 'text', array('label' => 'Article Title'))
    ->add('additionalField', 'checkbox', array(
        'label'     => 'Approved',
        'required'  => false,
        'mapped' => false
    ))
;
```

And in the controller check if the value in the form is true and set the datetime before persisting and flushing.

```
if($form->get('additionalField')->getData())
 $article->setitemApproved(new \DateTime());
```